# How do I use regex to match alphabetical characters only?

Tags: r

I want to `gsub` a string that contains only characters and white spaces, for example the string `"to delete"`. I have tried this:

```
gsub('[^[:alpha:]$]',NA, "to delete", ignore.case=T)
```

But I get an NA also when the string contains digits, for example:

```
gsub('[^[:alpha:]$]',NA, "to 1 delete", ignore.case=T)
```

Anybody could tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `gsub` is meant to replace strings with other strings. Are you trying just to match? Then you might want to use `grep()` instead. Otherwise what is the replacement you are trying to do?

Comment: `[:alpha:]` means only `[a-zA-Z]`. It doesn't includes `space`. [Check this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)

Comment: I am trying to match, then replace. I want to replace strings such as "to delete" with an NA, however I do not want strings such as "to 1 delete" to be replaced.

Still wondering why somebody down-voted too...

Comment: @42- That's incorrect. You can see it easily trying something like `gsub('hi',NA, 'hi')`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex only tests for a single unanchored bracket expression. This means that any string that has *any* character which matches the bracket expression will match the regex.

Your bracket expression tests for "not alphabetic not dollar". This matches many things, including spaces, digits, and all punctuation characters other than dollar.

It sounds like you want to match only strings which consist *in their entirety* of only alphabetic and whitespace characters. To achieve that you need an anchored multiplied bracket expression.

Also, you don't need `gsub()` for this; you only need `sub()`, since a regex that can only match the entirety of the input string cannot match multiple times within the input string.

Also, you don't need `ignore.case=T`, since the `[:alpha:]` character class already matches all alphabetics, regardless of letter-case.

```
regex <- '^[[:alpha:][:space:]]*$';
sub(regex,NA,'to delete');
## [1] NA
sub(regex,NA,'to 1 delete');
## [1] "to 1 delete"
```

Comment: Thanks for the extensive explanation.